# Can anyone explain these python nested loop please

Tags: python, nested-loops

I have doubt in these python nested for loop, that how the inner loop is executing can anyone resolve my problem here

```py
for i in range(1, 4):
    print(i)
    for j in range(1, i):
        print(j)
```

Comment: Add `print("i=", i) ` and `print("j=", j)` to understand it better.

Comment: I suggest you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: surround your code with \`\`\` before and after so that it appears properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your `for` loops are counting numbers from 1 to the upper limit minus 1.

Your code will run as follows:

Starting with `i=1`, it will print out a `1` and then `j` will go from `1` to `0`, that is it will take up no values and `j` won't be printed.

Next, `i` will become `2`, and then `j` will go from `1` to `2`, resulting in the output `1` from `j`.

This will continue, and the overall output will be:

```
(i)1
(i)2
(j)1
(i)3
(j)1
(j)2
```

The stuff in the brackets show which variable is being printed.

Answer (score 0):

For one your code example is poorly formatted.
I am assuming this is how the code is.

```
for i in range(1, 4):
  print(i) 
  for j in range(1, i):
    print(j)
```

This is a very simple for loop example, I'll go over two iterations that should make it clear.
Let's look at the outer for loop, it goes from 1 to 3 (4 exclusive)

`i=1` now, j will go from 1 to i i.e. 1 to 1.
The inner loop will now look as follows:

```
..
  for j in range(1, 1):
    print(j)
```

As range(1, 1), 1 will be exclusive, hence this loop will not run.
So out of Iteration 1:

```
1 # print(i)
```

=====
`i=2`, now, j will go from 1 to i i.e. 1 to 2.
outer loop will print 2, and now inner loop will look like:

```
..
  for j in range(1, 2):
    print(j)
```

This will print 1, as 2 is excluded limit.
Now output will be

```
2 # outer loop
1 # Inner loop.
```

On similar retrospection, the last iteration at `i=3`
Will give output:

```
3 # outer loop print(i)
1 # inner loop print(j)
2 # inner loop print(j)
```

Combining all three the final output would be

```
1 # outer
2 # outer
1 # inner
3 # outer
1 # inner
2 # inner
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your clear explanation